# ERROR: column "none" does not exist at character 67

Tags: postgresql, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-sawtooth

I tried to run this repo in my local mac machine (https://github.com/hyperledger/education-sawtooth-simple-supply).

I followed the steps to run the application in the README.md

> To run the application, navigate to the project's root directory, then
>   use this command:
>
> docker-compose up

However, when I open console for simple-supply-postgres, it keeps giving an error: `ERROR: column "none" does not exist at character 67`.

[image]

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: How to fix? Don't reference columns that don't exist in your SQL

Comment: Yeah, that's one method to fix it. but I'm still curious which part of the system makes this problem occur. Because it supposed to run properly according to the readme.md